# Help with robot bimanual manipulator impedance controller

Tags: ros, gazebo, control, ros-control

I have question with how should I focus the development of a impedance controller for two robots. I already built a controller for one arm but after a thorough search if literature or examples I didn't found how people focuses in order to build a cartesian impedance control for two robot arms. I already launched a gazebo simulation with two robots but when I use my controller loaded twice for each of the robots I'm getting lots of issues, and I wonder if I'm focusing wrongly how to make a controller for this use case.

Should I just load a controller twice for each of the arms or should I create a new controller able to handle both arms?

Also, if someone knows about a book of how to implement this type of controllers please let me know!

Thnaks in advance